# sliding images in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have background image slider. I want to slide images in very smooth way.

```
body {
  /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND1.jpg);


  /* Image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Image doesn't repeat */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Makes the image fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content height is greater than the image height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based on its container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Pick a solid background color that will be displayed while the background image is loading */
  background-color:#464646;

  /* SHORTHAND CSS NOTATION
   * background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
   */
background-position:0px 33px;


   }

/* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
     * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND1.jpg);
  }
    }
 #b1 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND1.jpg); }
#b2 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND2 .jpg); }
#b3 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND3.jpg); }
#b4 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND4.jpg); }
#b5 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND1.jpg); }
#b6 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND2.jpg); }
#b7 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND3.jpg); }
#b8 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND4.jpg); }
#b9 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND3.jpg); }
#b10 { background-image: url(images/BACKGROUND1.jpg); }


    <html>
       <a href="#">next/</a>
         <a href="#">previuous/</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

I want to change background images on click also. I am not expert in JavaScript. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> [bootstrap corousel js](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

That is easy javascript framework with which you can fulfill your requirement.

Next time when you ask any question kindly check the spelling of the words you type and explain in a crisp way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have so far, what you want to do is use the Javascript so that it replaces the body id on a specified click with the next one in your array (b1 through b10).  This will take care of the moving between background images:

```
var body_ids = [
"b1",
"b2",
"b3",
"b4",
"b5",
"b6",
"b7",
"b8",
"b9",
"b10"
];
var current_body_id_index = 0;

var next_click = document.getElementById("click_next");
next_click.addEventListener("click", setNextBodyBackground);

var click_previous = document.getElementById("click_previous");
click_previous.addEventListener("click", setPreviousBodyBackground);


function setNextBodyBackground() {
  current_body_id_index++;
  if (current_body_id_index > 9) {
    current_body_id_index = 0;
  }
  document.body.id = body_ids[current_body_id_index];
}

function setPreviousBodyBackground() {
  current_body_id_index--;
  if (current_body_id_index < 0) {
    current_body_id_index = 9;
  }
  document.body.id = body_ids[current_body_id_index];
}
```

Then, for your transition between sides you can add something like this to "body" portion of your css:

```
-webkit-transition: background 0.6s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.6s linear;
      transition: background 0.6s linear;
```

This creates a transition effect every time the background is changed.  You can modify this to create different effects.

I put all this into an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7dkr55v/8/).